# Can Mercurial create its own symbolic link format from Windows?

Tags: windows, mercurial, symlink

I know that Mercurial doesn't support symbolic links in repos on Windows; I can live with that, though an implementation using NTFS symlinks would be nice for those who can enable the privilege on their Windows boxes for non-admins.

What I'm wondering is about the way that Mercurial treats actual links from a Unix repository when the repo is seen on a Windows machine. If I update from a repo with a symlink in on my Windows development machine, I see that the link is changed into an actual file with the target of the link in it as text.

*Somehow*, Mercurial knows even on Windows that the file was originally a symlink, even when it is stored as a real file. If I edit the contents of the file in Windows, I can change the target of the symlink, because it's still recorded as being a symlink by Mercurial - when I push back to Unix, the symlink is pointing to the new location.

So. How do I mark a file that I've created in Windows as a symlink? It's clear that Mercurial could push such a symlink into the Unix filesystem, but I don't know how to mark it as such without creating the link first under Unix.

Is there a flag that can be set?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is [no work-around on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712267/110204). You could write an extension that would let you set the symlink bit for a file on Windows, though. This extension will probably have to override [`dirstate.flagfunc`](http://selenic.com/hg/file/2.1.2/mercurial/dirstate.py#l155), which is the function used when asking for the "flags" (execute and symlink bit) for a file.

See also [Issue 1825](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1825) for the overall feature of making Mercurial create Windows symlinks in a checkout. It's marked "done, could-be-better" so it's unlikely to change any time soon.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't want to create a Windows symlink; I just want to create a one-line text file that has a target as its content that will get turned into a symlink when I push to Unix. Files that are already known as symlinks by Mercurial go back as proper symlinks - can I tell Mercurial that a particular text file I create should to the same thing? Is that the bit I could write an extension for, and if so, do you have any pointers for where I should start looking at code in Mercurial? Thanks.

Comment: @IainHallam: sure, I've updated the answer with a pointer to what I think will be the relevant function to override.