# Adding symlink to repository on windows

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Mercurial allows versioning symlinks in a repository. On unix they are created as symlinks on checkout while on windows symlinks are not supported.

Instead Mercurial apparently creates a "special" text-file for each symlink with its content being the target of the symlink. By modifying the content of this text file on a windows machine, one can change the target of the "symlink". ([See this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712267/348501))

**Is it similarly possible to create a new symlink in a Mercurial repository on a Windows machine?**

I imagine this would involve creating the "special text" file and then somehow telling mercurial to treat it as a symlink. Possibly with a workaround similar to [this workaround for setting the executable bit](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2020#c8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mercurial installation on Windows to try this, but using `hg import` (possibly `hg import --no-commit`) for the following file seems to work on OS X and should work on Windows:

```
diff --git a/link b/link
new file mode 120000
--- /dev/null
+++ b/link
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+other/file
\ No newline at end of file
```

Replace `link` with the name of the file that's supposed to be the symlink and `other/file` with the name of the file that it is to link to.

Note that the last line is important; it prevents a newline from being added to the end of the path.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time trying this out!